# MySQL - join multiple mapped tables and count records with different mapping conditions

Tags: mysql, join

It's the 3rd day I'm trying to write a MySQL query. Did lots of search, but it still doesn't work as expected. I'll try to simplify tables as much as possible

System has **tkr_restaurants** table:

```
restaurant_id | restaurant_name
1             | AA
2             | BB
3             | CC
```

Each restaurant has a division assigned (**tkr_divisions** table):

```
division_id | restaurant_id | division_name
1           | 1             | AA-1
2           | 1             | AA-2
3           | 2             | BB-1
```

Then there are meals in **tkr_meals_to_restaurants_divisions** table, where each meal can be assigned (mapped) to whole restaurant(s) and/or specific division(s). If meal is mapped to restaurant, all restaurant's divisions should see it. If meal is mapped to division(s), only specific division(s) should see it.

```
meal_id | mapped_restaurant_id | mapped_division_id
1       | 1                    | NULL
2       | NULL                 | 1
3       | NULL                 | 2
```

I need to display a list of restaurants and number of meals mapped to it depending on user permissions.

**Example 1**: if user has permissions to access whole **restaurant_id 1** and **restaurant_3** (and no specific divisions), then list should be:

```
AA | 3
CC | 0
```

(because user can access meals mapped to restaurant 1 + all its division, and restaurant 3 + all its divisions (even if restaurant 3 has no divisions/meals mapped))

**Example 2**: if user has permissions to access only **division_id 1**, then list should be:

```
AA | 1
```

(because user can only access meals mapped to division 1).

The closest query I could get is:

Example 1:

```
    SELECT *,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT meal_id) 
    FROM 
        tkr_meals_to_restaurants_divisions 
    WHERE 
 tkr_meals_to_restaurants_divisions.mapped_restaurant_id=tkr_restaurants.restaurant_id 
    OR tkr_meals_to_restaurants_divisions.mapped_division_id=tkr_divisions.division_id)AS total_meals
    FROM 
        tkr_restaurants 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tkr_divisions 
        ON tkr_restaurants.restaurant_id=tkr_divisions.restaurant_id 
    WHERE 
        tkr_restaurants.restaurant_id IN (1, 3) 
        OR tkr_restaurants.restaurant_id IN (
            SELECT restaurant_id 
            FROM tkr_divisions 
            WHERE division_id IN (NULL)
        ) 
    GROUP BY 
       tkr_restaurants.restaurant_id 
    ORDER BY 
        tkr_restaurants.restaurant_name
```

However, result was:

```
AA | 2
CC | 0
```

I believe I'm greatly over-complicating this query, but all the simpler queries I wrote produced even more inaccurate results.

Comment: Why in Example 2 the meal with `meal_id` 2 is not allowed? It is mapped to division 1

Comment: If you refer to example 2 result being `AA|1`, be aware that the number displays not the ID, but the total number of meals assigned to specific division (and the total number of meals in division 1 is 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this query:

```
SELECT 
FROM tkr_restaurants AS a 
JOIN tkr_divisions AS b 
ON a.restaurant_id = b.restaurant_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tkr_meals_to_restaurants_divisions AS c 
ON (c.mapped_restaurant_id = a.restaurant_id OR c.mapped_division_id = b.division_id)
```

As a Base four your further work. It combine all information into one table. If you add e.g. this:

```
WHERE a.restaurant_id IN (1, 3)
```

the result will be

```
| restaurant_id | restaurant_name | division_id | restaurant_id | division_name | meal_id | mapped_restaurant_id | mapped_division_id |
|---------------|-----------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|---------|----------------------|--------------------|
|             1 |              AA |           1 |             1 |          AA-1 |       1 |                    1 |             (null) |
|             1 |              AA |           2 |             1 |          AA-2 |       1 |                    1 |             (null) |
|             1 |              AA |           1 |             1 |          AA-1 |       2 |               (null) |                  1 |
|             1 |              AA |           2 |             1 |          AA-2 |       3 |               (null) |                  2 |
```

just count the distinct meal ids with `COUNT(DISTINCT c.meal_id)` and take the restaurant name to get `AA: 3` for your example 2

I used a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2b78/18/0

**[EDIT]**

Change `JOIN tkr_divisions AS b` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN tkr_divisions AS b`

Change `SELECT *` to `SELECT a.restaurant_name, COUNT(DISTINCT c.meal_id)`

Add a `GROUP BY a.restaurant_name` at the end.

Update the SQL Fiddle (new link)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to debug it now with some more examples on my system.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works just partially. When I run your code for 1st example, it counts meals properly, but restaurant with ID 3 is not displayed. If restaurant ID with 3 was used in query, it should also be displayed (even if it has no divisions/meals assigned). So the result should be

 `AA | 3
  CC | 0`

Comment: But why display Restaurant `CC` when `BB` is also 0?

Comment: Because if user has permission to use restaurant C, he must see the restaurant in the list (the HTML content will contain links like restaurant.php?restaurant_id=3 to perform other tasks with restaurant if user has permissions to access this restaurant).

Comment: Thank you, the updated version works perfectly! Just a quick question... Since there might multiple restaurants and divisions mapped to user at the same time, I guess it's safe to use such a query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c921e3 (I added 4th division/meal and combined 8th and 9th lines of your code into one line and separated them with OR). Seems to work for me, but didn't perform many tests yet.